# Haskell globbing with System.FilePath.Find

Tags: haskell

How can I list all files and directories matching the pattern `./d*/*/*.xml`? I would prefer reusing existing solution like `System.FilePath.Find` rather than rolling my own one.

This naïve solution does not work:

```
find always (filePath ~~? "./d*/*/*.xml") "."
```

Comment: Why doesn't it work?

Comment: @duplode thank you for the edit. it doesn't work because there are files there a python glob("./d*/*/*.xml") from same directory will list those xml files. it could be a bug  in the package System.FilePath.Find or i use the package wrong way ... when i know more or i have an other solution i will edit my post.

Comment: Looks like a bug. See https://github.com/bos/filemanip/issues/9 . While that isn't fixed, you can try the [Glob](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Glob) package (it has a module name clash with the `filemanip` you were trying to use, so you'll need a [package-qualified import](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/users_guide/syntax-extns.html#idp23944304) to use it).